# Difference between Nokogiri::XML and Nokogiri.parse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Both `puts Nokogiri::XML(xml)` and `puts Nokogiri.parse(xml)` return the same XML.
And yes, they both return XML:

```
 > Nokogiri::XML(xml).class
 => Nokogiri::XML::Document  
 > Nokogiri.parse(xml).class
 => Nokogiri::XML::Document
```

Yet when comparing the returned values, I get:

```
 > Nokogiri.parse(xml) === Nokogiri::XML(xml)
 => false 
 > Nokogiri.parse(xml) == Nokogiri::XML(xml)
 => false
```

What is difference between `Nokogiri::XML` and `Nokogiri.parse`?

Comment: Explicitly tell Nokogiri what the type of the document is, rather than allow it to determine. I have experienced times when the heuristic used is fooled, returning the wrong document type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nokogiri.parse` just attempts to detect if the string passed to it is HTML, then creates/returns either a `Nokogiri::XML` or `Nokogiri::HTML` instance with a preset ParseOption:

```
def parse string, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = nil
  doc =
    if string.respond_to?(:read) ||
      string =~ /^\s*<[^Hh>]*html/i # Probably html
      Nokogiri.HTML(
        string,
        url,
        encoding, options || XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML
      )
    else
      Nokogiri.XML(string, url, encoding,
                    options || XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_XML)
    end
  yield doc if block_given?
  doc
end
```

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri.rb#L66

The comparisons return false because == isn't comparing the contents of the object, just that they're different instances:

```
>> Nokogiri.parse(xml) == Nokogiri.parse(xml)
=> false
```

Comment: Would that also make `Nokogiri.parse(xml)` slower than `Nokogiri::XML(xml)`?

Comment: `Nokogiri.parse` would be very slightly slower, but the difference would be negligible.